# Emulate Inspector highlight on hover

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

I am trying to emulate the **Chrome/Firefox Inspector Highlighting** effect using just CSS. I can achieve it relatively well but...

If a child element is hovered, its parent is highlighted aswell. Do you know how I can fix this? In the below example hover over the header and you will see pretty much everything is highlighted. Only the header should be red.

```css
*:hover {
  position: relative;
}

*:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.25);
}
```

```html
<main style="height: 600px; position: relative;">
  <header style="height: 100px;">Title</header>
  
  <footer style="height: 100px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 50%;">Footer</footer>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approximation is to consider the other pseudo element to hide the one of the parent element:

```css
html *:hover {
  position: relative;
}

html *:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-99;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
  opacity: .7;
}
html *:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  z-index:-99;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
/* increase the order of each child to make it cover the parent*/
html *:hover *::before,
html *:hover *::after{
  z-index:-98;
}
html *:hover * *::before,
html *:hover * *::after{
  z-index:-97;
}
html *:hover * * *::before,
html *:hover * * *::after{
  z-index:-96;
}
html *:hover * * * *::before,
html *:hover * * * *::after{
  z-index:-95;
}
/* and so on ...*/
html * {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  padding:15px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<main style="height: 600px; position: relative;">
  <header style="height: 100px;">Title</header>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a sollicitudin ligula. Phasellus ipsum tellus, interdum in nisl volutpat, vulputate aliquet massa. Ut non vulputate nisi, elementum faucibus mauris. Nam elementum non nisl sit amet mattis. Pellentesque consequat commodo rhoncus. Qu</p>
  <footer style="height: 100px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 50%;">Footer</footer>
</main>
```

This is not a robust solution since any use of `z-index` or other properties in the document may break the trick:

```css
html *:hover {
  position: relative;
}

html *:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-99;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
  opacity: .7;
}
html *:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  z-index:-99;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
/* increase the order of each child to make it cover the parent*/
html *:hover *::before,
html *:hover *::after{
  z-index:-98;
}
html *:hover * *::before,
html *:hover * *::after{
  z-index:-97;
}
html *:hover * * *::before,
html *:hover * * *::after{
  z-index:-96;
}
html *:hover * * * *::before,
html *:hover * * * *::after{
  z-index:-95;
}
/* and so on ...*/
html * {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  padding:15px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<main style="height: 600px; position: relative;z-index:0;"> <!-- added a z-index here -->
  <header style="height: 100px;">Title</header>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a sollicitudin ligula. Phasellus ipsum tellus, interdum in nisl volutpat, vulputate aliquet massa. Ut non vulputate nisi, elementum faucibus mauris. Nam elementum non nisl sit amet mattis. Pellentesque consequat commodo rhoncus. Qu</p>
  <footer style="height: 100px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 50%;">Footer</footer>
</main>
```

You can fix the `z-index` issue by forcing them to `auto` but you may have other side effects:

```css
html *:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index:auto!important;
}

html *:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-99;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
  opacity: .7;
}
html *:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  z-index:-99;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
/* increase the order of each child to make it cover the parent*/
html *:hover *::before,
html *:hover *::after{
  z-index:-98;
}
html *:hover * *::before,
html *:hover * *::after{
  z-index:-97;
}
html *:hover * * *::before,
html *:hover * * *::after{
  z-index:-96;
}
html *:hover * * * *::before,
html *:hover * * * *::after{
  z-index:-95;
}
/* and so on ...*/
html * {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
}
html * {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  padding:15px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<main style="height: 600px; position: relative;z-index:0;"> <!-- added a z-index here -->
  <header style="height: 100px;">Title</header>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a sollicitudin ligula. Phasellus ipsum tellus, interdum in nisl volutpat, vulputate aliquet massa. Ut non vulputate nisi, elementum faucibus mauris. Nam elementum non nisl sit amet mattis. Pellentesque consequat commodo rhoncus. Qu</p>
  <footer style="height: 100px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 50%;">Footer</footer>
</main>
```

Comment: "This is not a robust solution since any use of z-index or other properties in the document may break the trick" - would using `!important` resolve that though?

Comment: @sazr I have added an update with important ;) it solves the issue but it may affect other things. I cannot know what because there is a lot of possibilities